# Find the length of a curved line in Matlab

Tags: matlab, line, pixel

I have a skeletonized binary image.
The image contains curved lines.
I want to be able to find the length of a line (number of pixels) between any two point (on the line of course).
How can I do it (in Matlab)?

Comment: I think you can scan the image from left to right, top to bottom, starting at the leftmost point till you reach the rightmost point and count each pixel of the line you cross by (which has a binary value of '1'). Sorry I can't provide MATLAB code for this at the moment...

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach for simple situations (where there are no loops etc, and your line is only a pixel wide)

1. Start at the startpoint, define as currentpoint and mark as visited
2. Go to an unvisited neighbor point of the currentpoint
3. Increase count by 1, mark as visited, define this point as currentpoint
4. If you reach the endpoint, stop. If you still have univisited neighbors, goto 2. If you run out of unvisited neighbors, reset count to zero and try walking from the startpoint (to explore the opposite direction).

Of course this can work in any programming language. Try to implement this in MATLAB and if you get stuck you can consider to ask a more specific question.